# Как отобразить второй select на основе данных выбранных в первом select?

Tags: php

Получаю JSON ответ в таком виде:

`[{"coin":"btc","name":"Bitcoin","date":"1367107200"},{"coin":"eth","name":"Ethereum","date":"1438905600"},{"coin":"bnb","name":"Binance Coin","date":"1505520000"}]`

Далее даю возможность пользователю выбрать валюту с помощью select

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="result.php">

<select name="coin_name" class="form-control">
<?php
foreach($coins as $item) {
  echo '<option value="' . $item['coin'] . '">' . $item['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>

<select name="date" class="form-control">
<?php
foreach($coins as $item) {

  $times = date('m-d-Y', $item['date']);

  echo '<option value="' . $item['date'] . '">' . $times . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>

</form>
```

Json отдает еще и стартовую дату в формате `1367107200`

Как максимально удобно и просто дать возможность пользователю **выбрать дату**, где начальной датой должна быть метка `$item['date']` которая в каждом случае отдает индивидуальную старт дату, пример, `1367107200`?

**Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе конкретной монеты в первом select, во втором селекте с датами (возможно календарем) отображались даты относящиеся к данной монете?**

Т.е. некий календарь или список: числа месяца, месяц и год со стартовой датой из `$item['date']`, чтобы далее отправить post запрос с параметрами `coin_name` и `date` для дальнейшей обработки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В post можно отправить дату как есть, пример, 01-12-2020

Comment: делается с помощью ajax. При выборе первого элемента делаете запрос на сервер. Он вам возвращает данные для второго элемента. Заполняете второй элемента.